# elixir how to map and reduce at the same time without going through the map twice

Tags: functional-programming, elixir

I have list of map of orders that contain

```
%{price, order_details}
```

I wanted to get the total_price in that orders and I also want to return and array of changeset that was build using the order_details of each element in that map. 
I can't find a way to do it without using one reduce and one map but that is two trip in to the list. it is that a good practice in functional programming?

Comment: Did you try https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#map_reduce/3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming the data looks like this:

```
list = [
  %{price: 1, order_details: "foo"},
  %{price: 2, order_details: "bar"},
  %{price: 3, order_details: "baz"},
]
```

You can still use `reduce` with a tuple of sum and list as the accumulator.

```
list
|> Enum.reduce({0, []}, fn x, {sum, list} ->
  {sum + x.price, [x.order_details | list]}
end)
|> IO.inspect
```

Output:

```
{6, ["baz", "bar", "foo"]}
```

Answer (score 5):

Also answer by @Dogbert is perfectly valid, there is a built-in for doing map-reduce in Elixir ([`Enum.map_reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#map_reduce/3)):

```rb
list = [
  %{price: 1, order_details: "foo"},
  %{price: 2, order_details: "bar"},
  %{price: 3, order_details: "baz"},
]
Enum.map_reduce(list, 0, fn(%{order_details: od, price: p}, acc) ->
  {od, acc + p} # `od` is a mapper, `acc + p` is a reducer
end)
#⇒ {["foo", "bar", "baz"], 6}
```